# How to break outer loops from inner structures that respond break (loops/switch)

Tags: loops, nested-loops, swift

How to I break an outer loop from within an nested structure that responds to the `break` statement in Swift?

For example:

```
while someCondition {
    if someOtherCondition {
        switch (someValue) {
            case 0:     // do something
            case 1:     // exit loop
            case 2...5: // do something else
            default:    break
        }
    } else {
        someCondition = false
    }
}
```

The `break` will only get me out of the `switch`, and in Swift, it has to be used as empty cases are not allowed.  How can I entirely exit the loop from within the `switch`?

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Swift allows for [labeled statements](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID141).  Using a labeled statement, you can specify which which control structure you want to `break` from no matter how deeply you nest your loops (although, generally, less nesting is better from a readability standpoint).  This also works for `continue`.

Example:

```
outerLoop: while someCondition {
    if someOtherCondition {
        switch (someValue) {
            case 0:     // do something
            case 1:     break outerLoop // exit loop
            case 2...5: // do something else
            default:    break
        }
    } else {
        someCondition = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Label the loop as outerLoop and whenever needed user break Label: i.e. break outerLoop in our case.

```
outerLoop: for indexValue in 0..<arr.count-1 {
            if arr[indexValue] > arr[indexValue+1] {
                break outerLoop
            } 
        }
```